# How to publish multiple messages to single queue with different routing key in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq

Here is my code:

```
package pushnotiruntest;

import com.rabbitmq.client.BuiltinExchangeType;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Send extends Thread {

   String name = "";
   String app_type = "";
   private static final String EXCHANGE_NAME = "topic_exchange";

    public void run()
    {
        ConnectionFactory connFac = new ConnectionFactory();
        connFac.setHost("localhost");

        try {

                Connection conn = connFac.newConnection();
                Channel channel = conn.createChannel();
                channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, BuiltinExchangeType.TOPIC);
                for(int j=1; j<=20000; j++)
                {
                    //randomWait();

                    String routingKey = j+"."+"update"+"."+app_type;
                    String msg = name;
                    channel.basicPublish(EXCHANGE_NAME, routingKey, null, msg.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                    System.out.println("Sent " + routingKey + " : " + msg + "");
                }

                channel.close();
                conn.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Send.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.println("Exception1 :--"+ex);

        } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Send.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.println("Exception 2:--"+ex);
        }
    }

    /*void randomWait()
    {
        try {
           Thread.currentThread().sleep((long)(3*Math.random()));
        } catch (InterruptedException x) {
           System.out.println("Interrupted!");
        }
    }*/

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        Send test1 = new Send();
        test1.name = "Hello ANDROID";
        test1.app_type = "ANDROID";
        Send test2 = new Send();
        test2.name = "Hello IOS";
        test2.app_type = "IOS";
        Send test3 = new Send();
        test3.name = "Hello WINDOWS";
        test3.app_type = "WINDOWS";

        test1.start();
        test2.start();        
        test3.start();
    }
}

//javac -cp amqp-client-4.0.2.jar Send.java Recv.java

//java -cp .;amqp-client-4.0.2.jar;slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar;slf4j-simple-1.7.22.jar Recv

//java -cp .;amqp-client-4.0.2.jar;slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar;slf4j-simple-1.7.22.jar 
Send
```

I am writing a code in Java (message broker used is RabbitMQ) where I want to store messages send by the producers in a single queue with different routing key.

And fetch that messages with respect to there pattern for different consumers
that matches the routing key pattern. (I am using Topic exchange for the pattern matching).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need two consumers, you have to use two queues. 
The binding if from `exchange` to `queue(s)` you cannot decide the routing key during the subscription.

You can bind more routing key to the same queue, but you can't consume it filtering by the key.

I think you need something like:

```
channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, BuiltinExchangeType.TOPIC);
channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME_1, true, false, false, null);
channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME_2, true, false, false, null);
channel.queueBind(QUEUE_NAME_1, EXCHANGE_NAME, "my.rk.1");
channel.queueBind(QUEUE_NAME_2, EXCHANGE_NAME, "my.rk.2");
channel_consumer_1.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME_1, false, new DefaultConsumer(channel_consumer) {...}
....
channel_consumer_2.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME_2, false, new DefaultConsumer(channel_consumer) {...}
```

Comment: If I have to send thousands of messages to different different apps (like push notification) so creating the queue for each may create many numbers of queues, which may difficult to handle by the server. what I want is publishing the messages into the queue on priority basis and also getting back that messages respective to their consumer (i.e according to app id).

Comment: you have to create one queue for device

Comment: can you please explain

Comment: do you know how to bind multiple consumer to single queue with different binding key ?

Comment: As I said: you can bind a queue with different routing-keys, not the consumers